# parse initialization and maintain sessions in php sdk

Tags: php, wordpress, parse-platform

I am making a plugin in WordPress. I have installed PHP-SDK with my plugin. I am initializing my parse by the setting of plugin. My problem is that, I have to initialize the parse every time by sending a query with my form. I want the parse to initialize once until user changes the app_id, rest_api and master_key. How to maintain the parse initialization once. I want to fill the form just once until user itself changes.

My form Code:

```
<form method="post" 
action="http://.../wp-content/plugins/wp-link-with-parse/php-sdk/test.php"> 
<?php settings_fields( 'wp-parse-settings-group' ); ?>
<?php do_settings_sections( 'wp-parse-settings-group' ); ?>
<table class="form-table">
<p class="wp_parse_required_fields">* Required Field</p>
<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row">Application ID* </th>
<td><input type="text" required name="app_id" value="<?php $options['app_id'] ?>/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row">REST API Key* </th>
<td><input type="text" required name="rest_api" value="<?php $options['rest_api'] ?>" />
</td>
</tr><tr valign="top">
<th scope="row">Master Key</th>
<td><input type="text" name="master_key" 
value="<?php $options['master_key'] ?>" /></td>
</tr></table>
<input  name="submit" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="save options" />
</form>
```

test.php where this form is submitting

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Parse\ParseClient;
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$app_id = $_POST['app_id'];
$rest_api = $_POST['rest_api'];
$master_key = $_POST['master_key'];
ParseClient::initialize($app_id, $rest_api, $master_key);
header("location:http://....com/?page_id=40");
}
use Parse\ParseUser;
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
try {
$user = ParseUser::logIn($username, $password);
header("location:http://...com/?page_id=2");
// Do stuff after successful login.
} catch (ParseException $error) {
// The login failed. Check error to see why.
echo "Something getting Wrong";
}
}
?>
```

**My second Question:**

If i have successfully initialize the parse. How I will maintain my user session in the WordPress for parse user. Basically I want to retrieve the data from the parse using my wordpress plugin.

Thanks in advance. I hope you will understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

To save the session you can Follow the Parse tutorial, but to be sure you store the Session you first need to set the ParseSessionStorage. The final result would be:

```
require 'assets/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start(); // Make Sure you Put the session_start(); after you put the Autoload !

use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseSessionStorage;

ParseClient::initialize('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');

//The Parse PHP docs are not that well covered and they missed a very important part.  you should setup the storage before. This is the Answer
ParseClient::setStorage( new ParseSessionStorage() );

//You get the current User
$user = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();

//You can then get the session token as follows:
$sessionToken = ParseUser::getCurrentUser()->getSessionToken();
```